# Could not start uwsgi process

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

Could not start uwsgi process via ini flag

```
uwsgi --ini file.ini
```

Not any uwsgi pids

```
ps aux | grep uwsgi
root     31605  0.0  0.3   5732   768 pts/0    S+   06:46   0:00 grep uwsgi
```

file.ini

```
[uwsgi]

chdir =/var/www/lvpp/site

wsgi-file =/var/www/lvpp/lvpp.wsgi

master = true

processes = 1

chmod-socket=664

socket = /var/www/lvpp/lvpp.sock

pidfile= /var/www/lvpp/lvpp.pid

daemonize =/var/www/lvpp/logs/lvpp.log

vacuum = true

uid = www

gid = www

env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=settings
```

file lvpp.log

```
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.10 (32bit) on [Wed Apr  8 06:46:15 2015] ***
compiled with version: 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11) on 17 March   2015 21:29:09
os: Linux-2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.i686 #1 SMP Tue Sep 9 20:14:52 UTC 2014
machine: i686
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /var/www/lvpp
writing pidfile to /var/www/lvpp/lvpp.pid
detected binary path: /var/www/lvpp/site/env/bin/uwsgi
setgid() to 503
setuid() to 501
chdir() to /var/www/lvpp/site/
your processes number limit is 1812
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
error removing unix socket, unlink(): Permission denied [core/socket.c  line 198]
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 230]
```

It worked early.
But when I invoked `kill -9 uwsgi.pid` I could not start uwsgi process again.

Why can't I start uwsgi process again?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The key is:

```
error removing unix socket, unlink(): Permission denied [core/socket.c  line 198]
```

You (very probably) previously run a uwsgi instance as root creating the unix socket file with root permissions.

Now your instance (running instead as www) is not able to re-bind() that socket as it is not able to unlink it (no permissions)

Just remove the socket file and retry.

Comment: Note, this can be the issue even if it's not root and the sock file is 777. I had accidentally created the file with an "ubuntu" user and permissions were `-rwxrwxrwx`, and that still caused this error. Deleting the sock file and then restarting uwsgi-emperor fixed this for me.

Answer (score 21):

I was running into a very similar issue, except it still wouldn't work even after deleting the socket file. Turns out it was because uWSGI couldn't create a new one (it only existed because I ran uwsgi myself). The infuriatingly simple solution was to `chmod` the directory containing the socket file, allowing the `www` user to create and modify files there. Obvious now, but maybe this will help a future poor sap bashing their head against a wall, as I have been for too many hours today.

```
root@srv16:/var/run/uwsgi> ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root      60 Jul 16 07:11 .          #<-- problem
drwxr-xr-x 25 root    root     880 Jul 19 09:14 ..
srw-rw----  1 www-app www-data   0 Jul 16 07:11 app.socket 
               #^-- no idea how www-app managed to create that file

root@simsrv16:/var/run/uwsgi> chmod 777 .                  #<-- fix
```

Comment: yes. Interestingly somehow it managed to start the service and create the socket under the limited user, but then failed to delete it again until I changed the containing dir to "write for others"

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the main socket there could be also a stats socket. :)
The error log actually could be more specific abouth the path that isn't mentioned.

Comment: This is very helpful! I had the same issue, removed socket, pidfile, had correct permissions on the socket dir, but the error still kept appearing. And yes, it was about the stats socket!