# why do i have error "Address already in use"?

Tags: python, sockets, nginx, flask, uwsgi

i run my flask app, and it works good, but by the time the app is stopped  and in my uwsgi log

```
probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (127.0.0.1:9002).
    bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 764]
```

when i run touch touch_reload, app is working again. 
I run anything else on the server which may take the socket.

my conf:

```
nginx
server {
    listen 80;
    ....
    location / {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;
    }
    ....
}
server {
    listen 80;
    ....
    location / {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9003;
    }
    ....
}

uwsgi:
chdir = /var/www/../
module = wsgihandler
socket = 127.0.0.1:9003
wsgi-file = app/__init__.py
callable = app
master = true
chmod-socket = 664
uid = root
gid = root
processes = 4
socket-timeout = 180
post-buffering = 8192
max-requests = 1000
buffer-size = 32768
logto = /var/www/.../log/uwsgi.log
touch-reload = /var/www/.../touch_reload
```

Comment: It means port `9002` is already in use.

Comment: How are you stopping the process?

Comment: You probably must be using ctrl+z to stop the process but that is actually just hiding it. use ctrl+c to entirely stop

Comment: additionally you can use ps aux | grep 9002 to see what are using 9002 for

Comment: I did not stop the server, it is production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have same issue, but the problem was in sqlalchemy, try to add this:

```
@app.teardown_request
def shutdown_session(exception=None):
    from extension import db
    db.session.remove()
```

Answer (score 15):

This error means that port 9002 is already in use by another process. As per your logs that process is uwsgi `probably another instance of uWSGI is running on the same address (127.0.0.1:9002)`. May be the port was not released while you stop flask app and your wsgi server is restarted while you run `touch touch_reload`. You may try the following command to release the port.

```
sudo fuser -k 9002/tcp
```

If that is a tcp process and restart your wsgi server again to see if the port is already in use.

Answer (score 9):

maybe you stop uwsgi by crtl + z:

1. find the pid of process which take 8000

> $ lsof -i:8000

result maybe is:

```
COMMAND  PID       USER   FD   TYPE ...
uwsgi   9196       xxx    4u  xxx   ...
```

then

> $ kill 9196

Comment: It could also be useful(necessary) to use -9: ` kill -9 9196`

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I had a similar issue and discovered that I was running `uwsgi --http` when I should have been running `uwsgi --socket`.

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, you will get the same `Address already in use` error, even if you work with sockets.

```
               vvvvvvvvvvv-- Socket!
error removing unix socket, unlink(): Permission denied [core/socket.c line 198]
bind(): Address already in use [core/socket.c line 230]
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-- "Address"
```

If you DO use sockets, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29510480/could-not-start-uwsgi-process/37175197#37175197).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turned out my main module was already starting the application with `app.run()` on load.

So make sure `app.run()` is in the `if __name__ == '__main__'` section.